# What is a memetic proxy?

Tags: prompt-design, terminology, prompt-configuration

I came across this term with the negative impression on the AI Engineering which is:

> Try to avoid memetic proxy in the prompts

If I assume something it would be like "Imagine you are a brilliant quiz master" or so?

Comment: Could you provide a link (update the question) to where this negative view on memetic proxy is? Seems easier to find opinions that do recommend this approach.

Comment: are you asking what it is or why it should be avoided? Are you referring to this? https://ohandle.com/blog/prompt-engineering A quick search does not show any articles that say this should be avoided

Comment: Feel free to post the two other questions as two other separate questions.

Comment: @user13267 during a training session one of the data scientist mentioned few best practices while doing a prompt engineering like
1. avoiding memetic proxy (my question is why it should be avoided)
2. not to rely fully on the prompt engineering rather focus on training the model
3. best is to use single shot learning
and so on.

Comment: @Swesh is the session online? I think you should provide a link if available or at least more context. A quick search doesn't come up with anything about it having to be avoided

Comment: @user13267 it is an offline / internal to employee session! context is best practices to develop a chatgpt

Comment: @Swesh in that case it might just be someone's personal opinion

Answer (score 1):

As [user13267](https://genai.stackexchange.com/users/71/user13267) mentions in the comment, https://ohandle.com/blog/prompt-engineering gives a good definition:

> Task specification by memetic proxy
>
> Task specification by memetic proxy is a method where a cultural reference or analogy is used to convey a complex task. For example, instead of directly telling GPT-3 how to answer a moral question, you could ask it to answer the question as if it were Mahatma Gandhi, Ayn Rand, or Eliezer Yudkowsky. Each of these figures has a unique perspective and assumptions about the context of the question, which can help GPT-3 generate a more nuanced response.
>
> Another example of a memetic proxy is staging a dialogue between a teacher and student. If you want GPT-3 to explain something thoroughly, simply, and point out when you're wrong, it may be more reliable to present the discussion as a dialogue between a student and teacher. This archetypal situation reinforces the desired attributes and makes it more likely for GPT-3 to generate a response that meets those criteria.
>
> Some real concrete examples of using task specification by memetic proxy:
>
> *"What would Batman do if he were in this situation?"*
> *Here, the memetic proxy is Batman and the task is to determine what action to take in a specific situation. By invoking the character of Batman, GPT-3 can draw upon the cultural understanding of what Batman represents and how he typically behaves in certain situations to guide its response.*
>
> *"Imagine you're teaching a high school student how to solve a calculus problem."*
> *In this example, the memetic proxy is a teacher-student relationship and the task is to explain how to solve a calculus problem. By framing the task in this way, GPT-3 can draw upon cultural understandings of how teachers typically explain concepts to students, and how students typically ask questions and receive feedback from their teachers.*
>
> *"What would Elon Musk say about the future of space travel?"*
> *Here, the memetic proxy is Elon Musk and the task is to predict what he might say about the future of space travel. By invoking Elon Musk as a proxy for a particular perspective on space travel, GPT-3 can draw upon cultural understandings of his background, interests, and public statements to generate a plausible response.*